# Soap php force conversion of sequence to php array

Tags: php, arrays, xml, soap

I am testing Some Soap functionality with php

```
$soapClient = new CustomSoapClient($urlWsdl,[
     'exceptions' => true
     'trace' => true,
     'location' => $soapUrl
]); 

$soapResponse = $soapClient->__call('ProfileLookup',$methodArgs)
```

CustomSoapClient is a class which extends the base SoapClient class in order to log the xml request and response (in the "__doRequest" method.
$soapUrl is the location of a testing Soap Server which is able to answer to the method ProfileLookup by returning one or more result

the wsdl ($urlWsdl) define this method and its return types

```
<wsdl:operation name="ProfileLookup">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:ProfileLookupRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:ProfileLookupResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:message name="ProfileLookupResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="LookupResponse" element="n:LookupResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

 <xs:element name="LookupResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Result" type="c:ResultStatus"/>
            <xs:element name="ProfileLookups" type="tns:ProfileLookupList"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="ProfileLookup">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="PersonName" type="c:PersonName"/>
        ...
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="ProfileLookupList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ProfileLookup" type="tns:ProfileLookup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

If I call my Web Service and that this one return multiple results, the xml returned is OK

```
  <env:Body>
        <ns1:LookupResponse>
            <ns1:Result resultStatusFlag="SUCCESS"/>
            <ns1:ProfileLookups>
                <ns1:ProfileLookup>
                    <ns1:PersonName>
                    </ns1:PersonName>
                </ns1:ProfileLookup>
                <ns1:ProfileLookup>
                    <ns1:PersonName>
                    </ns1:PersonName>
                </ns1:ProfileLookup>
            </ns1:ProfileLookups>
        </ns1:LookupResponse>
    </env:Body>
```

and this is how this response is converted in php

```
[ProfileLookups] => stdClass Object (
    [ProfileLookup] => Array(
            [0] => stdClass Object (
                [PersonName] => stdClass Object()
            ),
            [1] => stdClass Object (
                [PersonName] => stdClass Object()
            )
    )
)
```

If I call the web service in order to get only one result I get the same xml structure

```
<env:Body>
            <ns1:LookupResponse>
                <ns1:Result resultStatusFlag="SUCCESS"/>
                <ns1:ProfileLookups>
                    <ns1:ProfileLookup>
                        <ns1:PersonName>
                        </ns1:PersonName>
                    </ns1:ProfileLookup>
                </ns1:ProfileLookups>
            </ns1:LookupResponse>
        </env:Body>
```

But the conversion to php value is different:

```
   [ProfileLookups] => stdClass Object (
    [ProfileLookup] => stdClass Object(
        [PersonName] => stdClass Object()
    )
   )
```

As you see, in the first Exemple, ProfileLookup is an array of objects of type "ProfileLookup", in the second one ProfileLookup is itself an object of type "ProfileLookup".

So the following code will lead to errors if only one item is returned.

```
foreach($soapResponse->ProfileLookups->ProfileLookup as $profileLookup){
   echo $profileLookup->PersonName->...
}
```

So of course, I could easely test if ProfileLookups->ProfileLookup is an array or an object and then force it to be an array. but that doesn't seems to be the proper way, as I can be faced to this problem in every part of the application.

What could be the solution to control the way SoapClient transform xml to php values?
Would it be better to parse the xml response myself ?
Could some library like Zend\Soap help in this use cases ?
Where could I find a reference documentation on the way SoapClient transform xml to php values?

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to enable `SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS` feature when creating the `SoapClient`:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to php generator so you'll always end up with PHP objects of the type you're expecting or an array if you're supposed to get an array. You should try the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project.